# rough idea on compression

Tags: compression, nas

I have a old EMC (about 12 years old, zero compression and zero de-dup) nas that I'm looking to replace.  Now that pretty much everything has built in compression, de-dup etc.  I want to get an idea on what size I need to look into.

On my nas it has been used as file storage.  Text file, word docs, excel, database files, audio files, images, etc, etc, etc.

Is there a utility out there that I can have scan my NAS, look at all the files, then give me a report telling me how much space I would actually need if I was to get a system with built-in compression?
I don't expect it to be perfect, but a rough idea would be nice.

Comment: In most settings, i don't see this as the way to go (probably dominated by other factors as raid or not, current-gen HDD sizes per unit, HDD-slots per NAS) and would *never scale down*,but of course this depends on details not given. Without a clear idea of *duplication* within your files,i would not put too much hope into dedupe (and especially compression).And even if that analysis is important for you, some details would be helpful:if you got the space for ~ full copy; just init any dedupe-software (restic; borg...)with your files and check the results.I don't expect *dry-run/simul* support

Comment: If that space is not available and the assumption about dedupe-effects is there: decide if you need file-based boundaries or block-based boundaries and maybe script it yourself. The former is trivial, the latter will probably need some fingerprinting implementation. But both should be doable in some *in-memory analysis* setting. I would not bother with compression here (as i expect it to be without much effect).

Comment: "i don't see this as the way to go (probably dominated by other factors as raid or not, current-gen HDD sizes per unit, HDD-slots per NAS)"---- irrlevant as no matter how many drive slots you have, or the size of the drives in those slots the total space on the source remains the same, as for teh destination,   I am trying to find out what X space needs to be on the target.   number of slots, size of drives etc only dictates the amount of available space, not how much space is needed.    as stated in the original question  the original system has "zero compression and zero de-dup"

Comment: So assuming your original data is 600 GB... ready to be compressed/deduplicated to 400 GB. You will fill your NAS with a single 500GB HDD then? Despite the fact, that the sweet-spot of Space/Cost is very far away? What do you do with the need for RAID? You buy two 250GB HDDs?  Well... youi get the idea... And your *the total space on the source remains the same* surely is not valid in the general RAID scenario. You might get the idea, that your question is missing out on details which might result in comments/answers you don't want to hear.

Comment: ok, assume original data is 600 GB.   After de-dup and compression......the result is......X.    I am looking for X.    
how I come up with the available space on the target doesn't matter.   Single disk of 500gb, or  3 disks of 500 gb setup as raid 5+0.
once I know what X is, then i can build out the destination as needed.

Comment: "I want to get an idea on what size I need to look into."..  "Is there a utility ..? " and the question title "rough idea on compression" .. doesn't really relates.. you want to ask about the the idea of [ how different storage compression compares? ]  Or [ How to execute one? ] Hope you can define specifically where exactly did you stuck at.. (you may rephrase the question by editing it)